# How can I restore iOS in app purchase when an error occurred while purchasing?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm having a trouble with in app purchase things when an error is occurred.
I might be misunderstood in app purchase transaction, so let me know if there is something wrong.
In the payment queue observer is same.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
    switch(transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: 
            [self purchasedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed: 
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and in the restoreTransaction is

```
-(void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
    NSLog(@"restore");
    [app hideIndicatorView];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    });

    [self verifyReceipt];
}
```

I charge the in app currency, in the verifyReceipt method which looks like

```
- (void)verifyReceipt
{
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */

    if ([UIAlertController class]) {

        UIAlertController *alert =   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                      message:@"verify fail"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:nil];
        [alert addAction:ok];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"verify fail" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }


}else{

    //server confirmation with [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
}
```

It doesn't work when a user takes restore transaction.
(Normally, it occurred when the user has some network problem or etc...)
So, please tell me, my work flow is wrong? or I missed something?
Is there any way to test restore transaction?

Comment: You should not call `finishTransaction` until you have successfully processed the purchase. Is this a consumable purchase?  If so, it cannot be restored

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the comment, you mean I have to call finishTransaction after verifyReceipt, correct?  It is consumable, but I don't get it what you said it can't be restored. Is there no way to restore while purchasing kinda network error etc? If the item is consumable?

Comment: Yes, you should only call `finishTransaction` after you updated the balance or whatever (ie. verifyReceipt).  Consumable purchases cannot be restored. This is why you don't call `finishTransaction` until you are sure that everything is OK.   Say you get a network error updating the user's balance on your server; because you didn't call `finishTransaction` the transaction will be presented to your SK delegate the next time your app runs

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank for your kindness.